# flatten list of list of strings in python

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have the following list in python:

```
ipdb> xgboost_prediction
'[["2019-08-16 14:22:00.0", "ls5923_splunk", "False"]]'
```

and my goal is to append it to the csv file, which will happen on minute base.

Now, I thought I would convert is easily to pandas dataframe and append csv. But somehow I am struggling with it. How would I flatten it and convert to dataframe?

I tried:

```
ipdb> 
ipdb> list2 = [inner for item in xgboost_prediction for inner in ast.literal_eval(item)]
*** SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

ipdb> new_lst = [sub_val for val in xgboost_prediction for sub_val in eval(val)]
*** SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Please advice.

Comment: What is `type(xgboost_prediction)`?

Comment: If `xgboost_prediction` is truly a list, you should be able to do `new_lst = [sub_val for val in xgboost_prediction for sub_val in val]`.

Comment: this is the output: ipdb> new_lst
['[', '[', '"', '2', '0', '1', '9', '-', '0', '8', '-', '1', '6', ' ', '1', '4', ':', '2', '2', ':', '0', '0', '.', '0', '"', ',', ' ', '"', 'l', 's', '5', '9', '2', '3', '_', 's', 'p', 'l', 'u', 'n', 'k', '"', ',', ' ', '"', 'F', 'a', 'l', 's', 'e', '"', ']', ']']

Comment: That means `xgboost_prediction` is a string. You'll have to figure out why that is and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to append normally formatted values to a csv using pandas is overkill. You can simply convert your array to a comma separated string and append that to the file directly. If you think your string might have special characters you can also use the csv library which will automatically add the proper formatting to escape any strings.

```py
xgboost_prediction = [["2019-08-16 14:22:00.0", "ls5923_splunk", "False"]]

with open('outputfile.csv', 'a+') as f:
    # Incase you are appending multiple predictions
    for entry in xgboost_prediction:
        f.write(','.join(entry))
    f.write('\n')
```

Comment: I did the following:     with open('outputfile.csv', 'a+') as f:
        # Incase you are appending multiple predictions
        for entry in xgboost_prediction:
            f.write(entry)
        f.write('\n')   But unfortunately my file gets also the [[...]] brackets in it. How would I avoid it?

Comment: Your input data is likely a string instead of a list, try converting it to a list.

Comment: The classifier function looks as follows returning result, which becomes the xgboost_prediction: 

`...
        # classify
        result = model.predict(data)
        
        # reshape from 1d to 2d array as the output is a list
        result = numpy.array([result])     
        # Concatenate back the "TIMESTAMP" and "host" to the result / prediction
        result = numpy.concatenate((data_tst, data_host, result.T),axis=1)
        return result.tolist()`

How would I change it properly to get what I want?

Comment: It is difficult to read code in a comment, you just need to convert it to be a list of lists instead of a string.

Comment: If you want to post a new question for that I'm sure someone can help.